# How to update the same row after multiple user input?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of questions and when a user button clicks on one of the radio buttons depending on what the value is [0 or 1], the table is updated. What happens now at the moment is when a user clicks the radio button for a question, the value is inserted into the database but when another user clicks the radio button of that same question, another row is inserted instead of updating the row.

The code below sets up the question and radio button.

```
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE id='$data' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $a = $row['data'];

    $data_id = $row['data_id'];
    $first = '<h2>'.$a.'</h2>';
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM replies WHERE d_id='$data'");
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
        $ch = $row2['reply'];
        $val = $row2['val'];
        $replies .= '<label><input type="radio" name="radio" onclick = "vote()" value="'.$val.'">'.$ch.'</label> 
        <input type="hidden" id="did" value="'.$id.'" name="did">
        ';

    }
    $displ = ''.$first.','.$answers.',<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="submit" onClick = "post_reply()">';
    echo $displ;
   }
```

This is how the values are added into the database after a user clicks on a radio button:

```
    $q = intval($_GET['rads']);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','poll');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"");

if($q == 1){
    $sql="INSERT INTO stats (correct,wrong) VALUES (1,0)";

} else {
$sql="INSERT INTO stats (correct,wrong) VALUES (0,1)";  
//$sql = "UPDATE stats SET correct = correct + 0, wrong = wrong + 4 WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$lastId = mysqli_insert_id($con);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE stats SET question_id='$lastId' WHERE id='$lastId' LIMIT 1");
mysqli_close($con);
```

The table might look something like this. So the second row is also the same question as the first row.

```
id----|----question_id----|----corect---|---wrong---

1               1              1               0
2               2                0              1
```

So what I'm trying to avoid is inserting another row for the same question rather I'd like to update it so it looks something like this:

```
id----|----question_id----|----corect---|---wrong---

1               1              3              1
2                2              2             2
```

Another row can be inserted for a the next question. In the above table, the second row is a different question.

**EDIT** 
This is how the questions table looks like

```
 id----|----question_id----|----question-------|---type--------

    1               1              ...a..              tf
    2               2             ....b...             tf
```

Answers table

```
-------id----|----question_id----|----answer-------|---correct--------

        1               1              False              0
        2               1               True             1
        3               2               False             1
        4               2                True              0
```

0/1 indicates if the answer is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part:

```
if($q == 1){
    $sql="INSERT INTO stats (correct,wrong) VALUES (1,0)";

} else {
$sql="INSERT INTO stats (correct,wrong) VALUES (0,1)";  
//$sql = "UPDATE stats SET correct = correct + 0, wrong = wrong + 4 WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1";
}
```

Then find a way to get if there are stats for that question (and user?) (can't help more as I can't see the table), and
- Select the id from the stats table connecting to your conditions (can't see those code parts needed). Put the proper id returned to the $lastId variable instead of a new insert's result
- if stat for that question doesn't exist (select result is empty, fetch statement returns false/null, $lastId is false/null, etc.), then do an insert to the stats table where you set correct and wrong answers zero

Also replace the line before last line with the lines starting with plus:

```
-mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE stats SET question_id='$lastId' WHERE id='$lastId' LIMIT 1");
+if ($q == 1) {
+    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE stats SET correct += 1 WHERE id='$lastId'");
+} else {
     mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE stats SET wrong += 1 WHERE id='$lastId'");
+}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but when I try it the way you suggested, nothing enters the database. Also, if it's an empty db, can you insert data with an update statement?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't format properly my answer, but I tried to explain in the middle part, that you will need to create a flow (==write for yourself), which decides if you need to just select and then update, or you will need to insert also, and you will need to write it yourself unless I know more about how stats and questions and users table look like in your task.

Also later you will learn about PHP frameworks doing these automatically, but before that, unfortunately you need to take care of this manually.

Comment: I added the questions and answers table in the edits above. I'm just testing them as a non user at the moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure what is the task. But it can still work if you leave your current code, forget mine, and when asking data from the stat table, you ask for SUM(correct) and SUM(wrong) for the users(?) later(?). Or if stats table just meant to collect how many people answered wrong or correct, then select id from stats where question_id = $youAreGettingThisFromAnEarlierVarInTheCode and if that did not exist do an insert into values question_id, 0, 0

Comment: Thanks for your help though, I was thinking of doing sum if all else fails.